Why is the activity_main.xml file not working correctly?
I have just started learning android studio kotlin. I am stuck on this problem. I couldn't solve it no matter what I did. Please help. The changes I made in the activity_main.xml page are not applied when I run the emulator. Why is this happening?
The changes I made in the activity_main.xml page do not work in the emulator. Although "Hello Word" is written in the middle of the activity_main.xml page, only "Hello Android" is written in the upper left corner in the emulator.

Hi Subhan, welcome to SO. It would help others if you posted some code to show us whats going on, for example sharing your MainActivityand your activity_main.xml. It sounds like perhaps the text is being set in a different location for example your MainActivity.
